# unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier interface. "lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.network"

Tags: android, react-native, stripe-payments, android-security

I'm currently having an issue trying to get my android app accepted by Google.

Upon pushing the app to the Google Play Store I keep getting rejected with the following email:

`Your app(s) are using an unsafe implementation of the hostnameverifier interface. lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.network.d$1 lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.network.e$1`

I have done quite a lot of searching on here and on Github and all I can find is things related to Braintree. We are using Stripe to process our payments and upon searching the entire source we can only find PayPal linked to Stripe. We don't use "HostNameVerifier" anywhere. Is there something that just released that I have missed regarding Stripe?

We are using Stripe v20.19.1

Comment: It's hard to tell but you can try latest SDK version of 20.20.0, and open an issue on Stripe SDK repo.